# How to identify pixels corresponding to a particular GPS coordinates on an image?

Tags: python, gps, maps, gis

I have an google map image, in which GPS coordinates (Lat1, Long1) & (Lat2 , Long2) of two locations in the image are known and their corresponding pixels are also known as (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).

Now I have a new GPS coordinates of a location (lat3, long3) which falls with in the image. I need to find the pixels (x3,y3)on the image which corresponds to this location ?

Please help me with math for this, how to do it ?,

Comment: Determine the conversion using algebra. If lat1 is x1 and lat2 is x2 then lat3 is what? This isn’t a coding issue but hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the coordinate net is linear,

```
  x1 - x3       x1 - x2
----------- = -----------
Long1-Long3   Long1-Long2

  y1 - y3       y1 - y2
----------- = -----------
Lat1 - Lat3   Lat1 - Lat2
```

So,

```
x3 = x1 - (Long1 - Long3)*(x1 - x2) / (Long1 - Long2)
y3 = y1 - (Lat1 - Lat3)*(y1 - y2) / (Lat1 - Lat2)
```

The assumption is only reasonable if the scale is reasonably low (e.g. a city map, not a continent map) and far enough from polar regions.

Comment: thank you for the basic math. It worked out for me with little bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [repository](https://github.com/saadmalik95/MassPlotTool) that streamlines mass plotting a map image. Hope this helps.